Argument of type 'PublicKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Provider'
I wanna write a client to call program already deployed in devnet, below is the main part of my code
const idl = require('../idl/idl.json');

const wallet = useAnchorWallet();

// Create the provider
export const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(
  connection,
  wallet,
  anchor.AnchorProvider.defaultOptions()
);

anchor.setProvider(provider);

// Initialize the program
const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("dTwLMQBF1AR46Y3aufwQgXWaTCzgbFjyMEC9da3dV");
const program = new anchor.Program(idl as anchor.Idl, PROGRAM_ID, provider);

and the code get the error Property 'connection' is missing in type 'PublicKey' but required in type 'Provider'.

what version of anchor are you using?

If this is a react app, try adding a check for whether the wallet is initialized.
if (!wallet) {
    throw new WalletNotConnectedError();
}

const provider = new AnchorProvider(
    connection,
    wallet,
    AnchorProvider.defaultOptions()
);

